# Adding and Updating Solr and lucene field

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to solr. can someone address below questions.
1. Currently I have an index with 1.5 mill records. I am having a need to update value of a field to a new value. How do I do it. Will it be a re-indexing? Sample code will be helpful.

1. I have another need where I want to add a index field but don't want to reindex the entire content. I have document ids with me. For this requirement I can use lucene if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Currently I have an index with 1.5 mill records. I am having a need to update value of a field to a new value. How do I do it. Will it be a re-indexing? Sample code will be helpful.*

Well, the good news is that the latest versions of Solr (starting with 4.3 or 4.4, I think) allows you to do what they call Atomic Updates. See here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates

From the coding point of view, it as if you were only updating the desired field. Using the Java SolrJ API it's something like this:

Let's say you have a document with a multi value field called "stuffedAnimals". The field already contains "teddy bear" and "stuffed turtle" as values. You want to update it and add a new value like "pink fluffy flamingo". What you can do is:

```
SolrInputDocument updateDocument = new SolrInputDocument();
//here you must add the id field with the desired value, corresponding to the doc you want to update:
updateDocument.addField("id", 2312312);
//tell it to add the new value to the existing ones, rather then replace them with it:
updateDocument.addField("stuffedAnimals", new HashMap(){{put("add","pink fluffy flamingo");}});
```

Problem with this is performance:  what actually happens when you do this is that the document is removed and re-added entirely (not just the field). This is something you need to take into consideration if you plan on doing a lot of such operations.

*I have another need where I want to add a index field but don't want to reindex the entire content. I have document ids with me. For this requirement I can use lucene if that helps.*

Well, as I was saying above: when you update a field, the document is actually re-written entirely, so that means it's re-indexed with the new field as well. If you're using Solr 4.4 or earlier you need to declare the new fields in the schema.xml file. If you're using Solr 4.5 or newer you don't need to worry about the schema.xml any more.

Finally, as a remark for both questions: if you want to update a Solr document, make sure all its fields are marked as "stored" (stored=true in schema.xml). Since a partial update on a field translates into Solr removing and re-adding the document (with the update applied), if certain fields are not stored, Solr won't know what value to put in them after the update.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [atomic update](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) feature added in 4.0.
It allows You to change value of particular field without reindexing whole document.
Remember that all fields in your schema have to be stored(without copyFields). If You need further assistance please write more detailed description.